# Python: Web Scraping with Proxy Addresses: Unresolved IP Address Visibility Issue

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, asp.net-web-api, proxy, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am attempting to perform web scraping with proxy addresses using the Python Selenium library. However, I am encountering an issue where my IP address is still visible on the websites I visit.

```
       def proxy_addresses(proxy, user_agent, port):

         # Create a Firefox profile
         profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

         # Configure proxy settings
         profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
         profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", proxy)
         profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", port)

         # Optionally set user agent
         if user_agent:
                  profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)

         # Clear cookies and cache
         profile.set_preference("browser.cache.disk.enable", False)
         profile.set_preference("browser.cache.memory.enable", False)
         profile.set_preference("browser.cache.offline.enable", False)
         profile.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False)

         # Set the Firefox binary location
         binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')

        # Create the Firefox WebDriver instance with the configured profile
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary, 
        executable_path=r'C:\Users\dharm\geckodriver-v0.33.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')

        # Navigate to a website
        driver.get("https://google.com")

        # Perform a search
        search_box = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        search_box.send_keys("what is my IP")
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign proxy in firefox like this

```
...
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver import Proxy
...


def proxy_addresses(proxy, user_agent, port):
    ...
    options = FirefoxOptions()
    proxyToUse = Proxy()
    proxyToUse.http_proxy = proxy
    proxyToUse.ssl_proxy = proxy
    options.proxy = proxy
    ...
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(
               options=options,
               firefox_profile=profile,
               firefox_binary=binary, 
               executable_path=r'C:\Users\dharm\geckodriver-v0.33.0-win64\geckodriver.exe'
    )
```